# MSSQL How to select multiple rows into columns?

Tags: sql

I have a table structure with the following 3 columns:

Date, MessageType, MessageText

The Row data looks like this:

```
2017-06-22 | "Public" | "Test Message"
2017-06-22 | "Private" | "Test Message 2"
2017-06-22 | "Semi Private" | "Test Message 3"
```

I want to be able to output into the following structure:

```
DATE | "Public" | "Private" | "Semi Private"
2017-06-22 | "Test Message" | "Test Message 2" | "Test Message 3"
```

So I would be able to group by the Date, and have the different MessageType become column headers, with the MessageText per date.

Assume that each Date would only have one type of MessageType.

I am using MS SQL.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple pivot query on the `Date` column *might* be what you are looking for.  I said "might" because my answer assumes that there is only at most one of the three message types on each date.

```
SELECT
    Date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MessageType = 'Public'  THEN MessageText END) AS [Public],
    MAX(CASE WHEN MessageType = 'Private' THEN MessageText END) AS [Private],
    MAX(CASE WHEN MessageType = 'Semi Private'
             THEN MessageText END) AS [Semi Private]
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Date
```

Again, if this doesn't work for you, then edit your question and show data where it is failing.

Comment: What about the case where I do not know what the MessageType is? Is there a more generic query that can be written so that it auto generates the columns based on distinct MessageType?

Comment: Yes, you could use dynamic SQL for that.  It would be a lot more work, and also would invalidate my answer (I only answered because it appeared you would _not_ need dynamic SQL).